# Alternative to Scala .make() Array method?

Tags: arrays, scala

In the *Programming in Scala* (Ch. 10 on "Composition & Inheritance") book there is an `Array.make()` method invoked in one of the examples. It appears to accept an an `Int` and a `String` as its first and second parameters, respectively. The function is excerpted below:

```
private class UniformElement(
  ch: Char, 
  override val width: Int, 
  override val height: Int
) extends Element {
  private val line = ch.toString * width
  def contents = Array.make(height, line)
}
```

Attempting it in the terminal i get a `error: value make is not a member of object Array` error. I'm using an outdated copy and some other methods have been deprecated, but I can't seem to find an updated and/or alternative to this one.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think the equivalent alternative would be: `Array.fill(height)(line)` (Note the 2 separate parameter groups.)

Comment: @jwvh Thank you; this seems to do the trick!

Answer (score -2):

def contents = Array(height, line)
seems to work just fine